# Xamarin WebService Localhost

Tags: android, xamarin, localhost

I'm developing a project with Xamarin. I'm trying to bring data with Android Web Service. The WebService is running. The data comes to Local. But the androide doesn't come.

```
public partial class ListData : ContentPage
{
    private HttpClient client;
    URL url;
    Connection cnn;
    public ListData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new HttpClient();
        cnn = new Connection();
    }
    async void btnEkle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:44364/api/values");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url.ToString());
        var yanit = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString());
        var jsondata = yanit.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsondata);
    }
}
```

Comment: use the IP of the server, not localhost

Comment: https://192.168.2.246:44364/api/values      I've tried but i can not

Comment: if you are using IISExpress, is it setup to support remove requests?  This is NOT the default

Comment: Yes set to configure requests.